# Which JSONPath expression should I use to split my JSON string?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I want to apply `SplitJson` in order to split the following JSON file into 2 FlowFiles (according to `hits`):

```
    {"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":
      {"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},
            "hits":{"total":2,"max_score":0.0,
               "hits":   
               [
                 {"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_entry","_id":"111","_score":0.0,"_source":{"ZoneId":"1","OriginId":"1"},
                  "fields":{"ttime":[11000]}},

                 {"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_entry","_id":"222","_score":0.0,"_source":{"ZoneId":"1","OriginId":"2"},
                  "fields":{"ttime":[5000]}}

               ]
             }
    }
```

Which `JsonPath Expression` should I use? I tried `$.hits[*]`, but it splits the content according to the first level `hits`. In my case I have `hits[hits[...]]`, but how should I specify it in the expression?

**UPDATE:**

I want to get two FlowFiles:

FlowFile #1: `{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_entry","_id":"111","_score":0.0,"_source":{"ZoneId":"1","OriginId":"1"},"fields":{"ttime":[11000]}}`

FlowFile #2:
`{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_entry","_id":"222","_score":0.0,"_source":{"ZoneId":"1","OriginId":"2"},"fields":{"ttime":[5000]}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = $.hits.hits;
```

Will give you the array with 2 objects you desire.

```
var o1 = arr[0];
var o2 = arr[1];
```

Will give you 2 objects you desire.

```
var json1 = JSON.stringify(arr[0]);
var json2 = JSON.stringify(arr[1]);
```

Will give you 2 JSON files as requested. 
Is this what you needed?

Comment: yes, it works fine. Why `$.hits.hits[*]` was not working?

Comment: It should if you modify approach after.  See how result subtly differ at http://jsonpath.com/?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [website](http://jsonpath.com/) for testing JSONPath Index for your case.
The right answer is `$.hits.hits[*]`.

As mentioned DanteTheSmith, you can simply use `$.hits.hits` in your case. It depends on the post-processing. Both methods work fine.

Comment: No, it generates two JSON files with the same content. It does not work for me.

Comment: I want to get two FlowFile's: the first one containing `{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_entry","_id":"111","_score":0.0,"_source":{"ZoneId":"1","OriginId":"1"},"fields":{"ttime":[11000]}}`, and the second one containing `{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_entry","_id":"222","_score":0.0,"_source":{"ZoneId":"1","OriginId":"2"},"fields":{"ttime":[5000]}}`.